# How is listening to a state provider different from watching it?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

There is a state provider

```
final valueStateProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 50);
```

a possible solution to show modals is

```
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final value = ref.watch(valueStateProvider);
  ref.listen<int>(valueStateProvider, (prev, curr) {
    if (curr == 65) {
      // show a dialog
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Value is 65')),
      );
    }
});
...
```

but how is it different from the following one since the `ref` is watched here ?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final value = ref.watch(valueStateProvider);
  if (value == 65) {
      // show a dialog
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Value is 65')),
      );
  }
  ...
```

Should not the `value` be updated automatically since `watch` is used? Then what is the reason to use `watch` but not `read` here?

Comment: who said the riverpod is popular? there is only 10 views per hour!

Answer (score 1):

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final value = ref.watch(valueStateProvider);
  if (value == 65) {
      // show a dialog
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Value is 65')),
      );
  }
```

This code has the following bug: every time the Widget is rebuilt (which can happen at any time, Flutter just *does* it for fun sometimes) and your `value` is 65 the snackbar is shown. So at worst case every frame a new snackbar is shown.

---

`ref.watch(valueStateProvider)` will rebuild the Widget every time your *valueStateProvider* changes.

`ref.listen(valueStateProvider)` will run the provided callback every time the *valueStateProvider* changes.

So in your case you want to use `ref.listen`!

Answer (score 1):

Listening (`ref.listen`) does not trigger a rebuild of the widget, whereas `ref.watch` will trigger the `build` method whenever there is a change.